# If NaN then sum of columns else column - Python

Tags: python, pandas

I have the dataset:

[image]

The logic to be implemented: if prev_product_id is NaN then payment1+payment2 else payment2.

[image]

I've tried with the list comprehension:

```
column_names = ['payment1', 'payment2']
df['payment_corrected']= [df[column_names].sum(axis=1) if math.isnan(float(i))==True else df['payment2'] for i in df['prev_product_id']]
```

But got:

[image]

Why is there an array instead of row by row summation?

Comment: You are expected to add data as text, we can not copy the contents from image.

Comment: If it is helpful for you, please give me checkup and voteup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the code as below :

```
df["payment_corrected"] = df["payment2"]
df["payment_corrected"][(df["prev_product_id"].isna())] = df["payment1"][(df["prev_product_id"].isna())] + df["payment2"][(df["prev_product_id"].isna())]
```

Hope to be helpful for you.

Comment: Thank you! @lionking-123, allow me to check!

Comment: If it is helpful for you, please give me checkup and voteup.

Comment: Will do, just let me to finish one part of the code and test your piece!

Comment: Hello, didn't you check it, yet? If you check it, please give me review.

Comment: Thank you, lion, I am already using your logic on other parts! Very clever